# Countifs N Count across multiple criteria (in data validations) but not returning zero if data validated cell is blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to set up a formula where I can pull N counts based off multiple criteria including a date range.  A typical Countif formula could work in theory:

`=countifs(D2:D, J2, F2:F, J3, E2:E, J4, G2:G, J5, C2:C, ">="&TODAY()-7, C2:C, "<="&TODAY())`

However, the problem I am facing is I want to be able to still pull the N count even if I leave one or more data validated cells the formula is pulling off of blank.  In order to pull anything, you have to select one of the 4 data validated options. As you select more, the data gets more granular.  Currently if I leave one cell blank, I then get a zero on the return.  Need that not to happen

[image: Here is a sample data set that I created to seek help]

Any thoughts on how I could make this work?

I have done this with queries before, but I am not sure how to pull N count if use query.  Happy to go that route as well if its easiest

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(C:G, 
 "select C 
  where 1=1 "&
 IF(J2="",," and D = '"&J2&"'")&
 IF(J3="",," and F = '"&J3&"'")&
 IF(J4="",," and E = '"&J4&"'")&
 IF(J5="",," and G = '"&J5&"'")&
 " and C <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
   and C >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)))
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you so much @player0.  If I may please ask one more question - If I wanted to add in another parameter around also selecting the data if another cell equaled something like the brand of the fruit, would I pul that at the top where "select C.." lives or at the bottom where the date function lives?  Example: and H2:H = 'Dole'"

Comment: @VincentVolpe order where you put it it does not matter. it just needs to be after `where` attribute - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRfNy.png